# multiple has_many same models  Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many

Model: Category

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :postings
   has_and_belongs_to_many :volunteers
end
```

Model: Posting

```
class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
   has_many :volunteers, :through=>:signed_postings
end
```

Model: Volunteer

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
   has_many :postings, :through=>:signed_postings
end
```

---

Now here is the problem I am trying to solve.

I want to find out all the postings of the categories that the volunteer is interested in. The volunteer might be interested in more than one categories and posting might be assigned more than one categories.

### **ADDITIONAL INFO**

I also have another model SignedPosting:

```
class SignedPosting < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :volunteer
  belongs_to :posting

end
```

Now after adding the association **has_many postings, :through=> :categories, uniq=> :true** as suggested by **jdoe** in volunteer model, I have two **has_many associations** from volunteer to posting model but with different **:through**.

### I do not know how to solve this issue as the rails is not happy with two has_many associations to same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add:

```
# in Volunteer class
has_many postings, through: :categories, uniq: :true
```

and then just call:

```
Volunteer.find(1).postings
```

## Solving conflicts

On collision (if you already have `postings` assoc.) do the following:

```
# name 'postings_via_cats' isn't obligation. Name it as you want.
has_many postings_via_cats, through: :categories, source: :postings, uniq: :true 
                 ---------                        -----------------
```

Comment: jdoe, your suggestion worked but now I got two has_many associations to same model which rails did not like. I have no idea what to do. Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @user1449337 To solve your conflict you can name your association as you want, say, `postings_via_cats`. Just specify additional option: `source: :postings` in the `has_many`. Reflected this in my answer's update.